# Why doesn't my computer show Canon EOS 450D pictures taken with P setting?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, canon-450d, shooting-mode

I bought a used Canon EOS 450D, and whenever I take pictures with the P setting, I can see the pictures on the camera display, but when I take the SDcard out, I cannot see them. Obviously they are there since the camera shows them fine, but my computer will not. Anyone have this, or know what could be the cause?

I can see all pictures taken with AUTO setting and landscape etc. Only using the P setting seems to do this.

Comment: What are you using to look at them on the computer? Do you mean that they don't show up in the file listing at all, or that they give an error when you try to load them, or that they load, but are all black or otherwise wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a software setting. Make sure you don't have any filters, searches, etc. set in your photo software. Also, considering that it seems to be a computer/software issue, might help to tell us what computer and software you're using, and what happens if you try to read the images on a different computer.

Comment: What about Av, Tv, or M modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given many details, but I have a strong suspicion of what is wrong. Your camera is set to take pictures in RAW. It happens that for this model, RAW isn't available in the full-auto/scene modes, so in that case, it falls back to saving JPEG files.

There are two basic ways to resolve this. One would be to leave your camera as-is and use software which recognizes Canon's `.CR2` RAW files. The other is to configure your camera to save JPEG files in the more-advanced modes as well. Look at page 64 [of your manual](http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft31340/manual/CUG_EOS450D_EN_Flat.pdf), and change the setting to either one of the JPEG modes ("L", "M', "S"), or to "RAW + L", which saves *both* types of files. (This uses more space on the card, but gives you the most flexibility and is my personal preference.)

If you chose to use RAW, you'll need software which understands that. Canon offers [free downloads on their web site](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_slr/eos_450d.aspx?type=download&language=EN) for basic viewer and converter software for many operating systems. Many people prefer to invest in a more sophisticated program like Lightroom (which gets generally strong accolades from everyone). There are also various free software solutions, like [RawTherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply (to all others as well). I was thinking it might be because it saves in RAW format, but should those not show in windows explorer as well? I also could not find the setting where to check that on this camera, as it sadly did not come with a manual.

Comment: Is my guess right?

Comment: You are right. It is set to RAW format. Do you know a way to make those files visible on PC, OR to change it to always use JPEG?

Ninjaedit: the 12MP only seems to let you choose RAW. I guess M quality 6.3M saves JPEG files.

Comment: @ToniMoisio Edited with some software suggestions.

Comment: And yes, the RAW files will always be full resolution.

Comment: I am sure your suggestions will help me resolve this, thanks a million. Although my settings are set to RAW + L but i still cannot see the files when i plug the SDcard to my card reader, neither on the Mac or PC.

I will however try your suggested software, i am sure they can read the files. Strange thought that windows 7 cannot. (might be a setting thing in Win 7 tho)

Comment: Use the Canon software to download the files to your computer. (It helpfully lets you select an option to download just new images and creates a new folder for each shooting date.) I like the [Digital Workflow](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Photography-Tips/Digital-Workflow.aspx) article for tips about processing your photos with Canon's Digital Photo Professional software, which handles Canon RAW files very nicely.